# JAXB SAXParseException while generating models from *.xsd delivered by EURID (EPP Protocol)

Tags: java, xml, maven, jaxb, xsd

I'm trying to generate Java code from the *.xsd files delivered by EurID.

Currently I'm receiving several exceptions:

```
Error while parsing schema(s).Location [ file:~/src/main/resources/epp-1.0.xsd{375,32}].
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:~/src/main/resources/epp-1.0.xsd; lineNumber: 375; columnNumber: 32; src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'eppcom:minTokenType' to a(n) 'type definition' component.

[ERROR] Error while parsing schema(s).Location [ file:~/src/main/resources/nsgroup-1.0.xsd{86,42}].
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:~/src/main/resources/nsgroup-1.0.xsd; lineNumber: 86; columnNumber: 42; src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'euridcom:nsgType' to a(n) 'type definition' component.

[ERROR] Error while parsing schema(s).Location [ file:~/src/main/resources/domain-1.0.xsd{94,53}].
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:~/src/main/resources/domain-1.0.xsd; lineNumber: 94; columnNumber: 53; src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'host:addrType' to a(n) 'type definition' component.
```

The Maven plugin configuration looks like following:

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.8.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <schemaDirectory>src/main/resources</schemaDirectory>
                    <bindingDirectory>src/main/resources</bindingDirectory>
                    <bindingIncludes>
                        <include>bindings.xml</include>
                    </bindingIncludes>
                    <extension>true</extension>
                    <debug>true</debug>
                    <args>
                        <arg>-extension</arg>
                        <arg>-Xnamespace-prefix</arg>
                    </args>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jaxb2-namespace-prefix</artifactId>
                        <version>1.1</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
```

And the bindings.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<jxb:bindings version="1.0"
              xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
              xmlns:namespace="http://jaxb2-commons.dev.java.net/namespace-prefix"
              xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/bindingschema_2_0.xsd
              http://jaxb2-commons.dev.java.net/namespace-prefix http://java.net/projects/jaxb2-commons/sources/svn/content/namespace-prefix/trunk/src/main/resources/prefix-namespace-schema.xsd">

<jxb:bindings schemaLocation="authInfo-1.0.xsd">
        <jxb:schemaBindings>
            <jxb:package name="eu.eurid.xml.epp.authInfo"/>
        </jxb:schemaBindings>
        <jxb:bindings>
            <namespace:prefix name="authInfo"/>
        </jxb:bindings>
    </jxb:bindings>

    <jxb:bindings schemaLocation="epp-1.0.xsd">
        <jxb:schemaBindings>
            <jxb:package name="eu.eurid.xml.epp.epp"/>
        </jxb:schemaBindings>
        <jxb:bindings>
            <namespace:prefix name="epp"/>
        </jxb:bindings>
    </jxb:bindings>

    <jxb:bindings schemaLocation="eppcom-1.0.xsd">
        <jxb:schemaBindings>
            <jxb:package name="eu.eurid.xml.epp.eppcom"/>
        </jxb:schemaBindings>
        <jxb:bindings>
            <namespace:prefix name="eppcom"/>
        </jxb:bindings>
    </jxb:bindings>

    <jxb:bindings schemaLocation="contact-1.0.xsd">
        <jxb:schemaBindings>
            <jxb:package name="eu.eurid.xml.epp.contact"/>
        </jxb:schemaBindings>
        <jxb:bindings>
            <namespace:prefix name="contact"/>
        </jxb:bindings>
    </jxb:bindings>

    <jxb:bindings schemaLocation="contact-ext-1.0.xsd">
        <jxb:schemaBindings>
            <jxb:package name="eu.eurid.xml.epp.contact.ext"/>
        </jxb:schemaBindings>
        <jxb:bindings>
            <namespace:prefix name="contact-ext"/>
        </jxb:bindings>
    </jxb:bindings>

    <jxb:bindings schemaLocation="domain-1.0.xsd">
        <jxb:schemaBindings>
            <jxb:package name="eu.eurid.xml.epp.domain"/>
        </jxb:schemaBindings>
        <jxb:bindings>
            <namespace:prefix name="domain"/>
        </jxb:bindings>
    </jxb:bindings>

    <jxb:bindings schemaLocation="domain-ext-1.0.xsd">
        <jxb:schemaBindings>
            <jxb:package name="eu.eurid.xml.epp.domain.ext"/>
        </jxb:schemaBindings>
        <jxb:bindings>
            <namespace:prefix name="domain-ext"/>
        </jxb:bindings>
    </jxb:bindings>

    <jxb:bindings schemaLocation="dss-1.0.xsd">
        <jxb:schemaBindings>
            <jxb:package name="eu.eurid.xml.epp.dss"/>
        </jxb:schemaBindings>
        <jxb:bindings>
            <namespace:prefix name="dss"/>
        </jxb:bindings>
    </jxb:bindings>

    <jxb:bindings schemaLocation="dynUpdate-1.0.xsd">
        <jxb:schemaBindings>
            <jxb:package name="eu.eurid.xml.epp.dynupdate"/>
        </jxb:schemaBindings>
        <jxb:bindings>
            <namespace:prefix name="dynupdate"/>
        </jxb:bindings>
    </jxb:bindings>

    <jxb:bindings schemaLocation="euridcom-1.0.xsd">
        <jxb:schemaBindings>
            <jxb:package name="eu.eurid.xml.epp.euridcom"/>
        </jxb:schemaBindings>
        <jxb:bindings>
            <namespace:prefix name="euridcom"/>
        </jxb:bindings>
    </jxb:bindings>

    <jxb:bindings schemaLocation="host-1.0.xsd">
        <jxb:schemaBindings>
            <jxb:package name="eu.eurid.xml.epp.host"/>
        </jxb:schemaBindings>
        <jxb:bindings>
            <namespace:prefix name="host"/>
        </jxb:bindings>
    </jxb:bindings>

    <jxb:bindings schemaLocation="idn-1.0.xsd">
        <jxb:schemaBindings>
            <jxb:package name="eu.eurid.xml.epp.idn"/>
        </jxb:schemaBindings>
        <jxb:bindings>
            <namespace:prefix name="idn"/>
        </jxb:bindings>
    </jxb:bindings>

    <jxb:bindings schemaLocation="keygroup-1.1.xsd">
        <jxb:schemaBindings>
            <jxb:package name="eu.eurid.xml.epp.keygroup"/>
        </jxb:schemaBindings>
        <jxb:bindings>
            <namespace:prefix name="keygroup"/>
        </jxb:bindings>
    </jxb:bindings>

    <jxb:bindings schemaLocation="nsgroup-1.0.xsd">
        <jxb:schemaBindings>
            <jxb:package name="eu.eurid.xml.epp.nsgroup"/>
        </jxb:schemaBindings>
        <jxb:bindings>
            <namespace:prefix name="nsgroup"/>
        </jxb:bindings>
    </jxb:bindings>

    <jxb:bindings schemaLocation="poll-1.0.xsd">
        <jxb:schemaBindings>
            <jxb:package name="eu.eurid.xml.epp.poll"/>
        </jxb:schemaBindings>
        <jxb:bindings>
            <namespace:prefix name="poll"/>
        </jxb:bindings>
    </jxb:bindings>

    <jxb:bindings schemaLocation="secDNS-1.1.xsd">
        <jxb:schemaBindings>
            <jxb:package name="eu.eurid.xml.epp.secdns"/>
        </jxb:schemaBindings>
        <jxb:bindings>
            <namespace:prefix name="secdns"/>
        </jxb:bindings>
    </jxb:bindings>

    <jxb:bindings schemaLocation="registrar-1.0.xsd">
        <jxb:schemaBindings>
            <jxb:package name="eu.eurid.xml.epp.registrar"/>
        </jxb:schemaBindings>
        <jxb:bindings>
            <namespace:prefix name="registrar"/>
        </jxb:bindings>
    </jxb:bindings>
</jxb:bindings>
```

For the reference host.xsd file contents is here: http://pastebin.com/ZdAGrNXF
and eppcom.xsd is here: http://pastebin.com/hYSwXQ11

I've already spent like 5 days trying to figure out what is wrong - trying different combinations of maven plugin options etc. 
The SO's community is my last chance now.
Thank you in advance for the tips.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JRE/JDK I've used was not complete somehow. Installation of JDK with Java EE solved the problem of JaxB.

Answer (score 1):

I am changed xsd. Add attribute schemaLocation to import elements in all xsd schemas. Then generating of class was ok.

If I use catalog for resolving namespaces, then I have problems with duplicit definition of some elements.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem trying to validate xml with epp-1.0.xsd (http://www.iana.org/assignments/xml-registry/schema/epp-1.0.xsd) and replacing

```
<import namespace="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:eppcom-1.0"/>
```

in epp-1.0.xsd file with

```
<import namespace="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:eppcom-1.0" schemaLocation="http://www.iana.org/assignments/xml-registry/schema/eppcom-1.0.xsd"/>
```

solved the problem.